# MySQL service won't start anymore because of OS error 105

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

Complete MySQL error Log: https://pastebin.com/20QX1ZSc

Overnight my MySQL install suddenly stopped working...
I am using **ubuntu 20.04**

systemctl:

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-05-13 14:50:18 CEST; 17min ago
    Process: 4562 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 4570 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=3)
   Main PID: 4570 (code=exited, status=3)
     Status: "Server startup in progress"

May 13 14:50:18 vault systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
May 13 14:50:18 vault systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
May 13 14:50:18 vault systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
May 13 14:50:18 vault systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 13 14:50:18 vault systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

/var/log/mysql:

```
2021-05-13T12:50:18.017977Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) starting as process 4570
2021-05-13T12:50:18.032753Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-05-13T12:50:18.194467Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-05-13T12:50:18.428966Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012637] [InnoDB] 16384 bytes should have been read. Only 12288 bytes read. Retrying for the remaining bytes.
2021-05-13T12:50:18.604489Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012638] [InnoDB] Retry attempts for reading partial data failed.
2021-05-13T12:50:18.604910Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012642] [InnoDB] Tried to read 16384 bytes at offset 16498688, but was only able to read 12288
2021-05-13T12:50:18.605273Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012592] [InnoDB] Operating system error number 5 in a file operation.
2021-05-13T12:50:18.605645Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012596] [InnoDB] Error number 5 means 'Input/output error'
2021-05-13T12:50:18.606374Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012646] [InnoDB] File mysql.ibd: 'read' returned OS error 105. Cannot continue operation
2021-05-13T12:50:18.606762Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012981] [InnoDB] Cannot continue operation.
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a data/ file corruption. Try these steps:

1. remove the syslog entry under --> /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf
2. backup & remove both ib_logfile0 & ib_logfile1 files under --> /var/lib/mysql
3. remove entry innodb_force_recovery = 1 from --> etc/mysql/my.cnf
4. run command --> `sudo service mysql start`

reference [Forcing InnoDB Recovery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html)

Comment: It worked for me, thanks. That's not the only post where I saw this solution but the error thrown here (https://talk.plesk.com/threads/mysql-database-is-not-starting-since-today-morning.343788) were more explicit than this one which I actually had.
So for such kind of error, we always have to consider corrupted logfiles?